# How to create a django listing with Select2 and Formset?

Tags: django

I have two tables:

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Zyt2.jpg)

I need to create a component that lists the tables and presents itself as follows:

[FrontEnd Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6Wvc.jpg)

I use "Django == 2.2" and "django-select2 == 7.1.0".

The Models that create the three tables are below

**Model "Grupo"**

```
class Grupo(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    id_condominio = models.ForeignKey(
        Condominio,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )  

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'grupo'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

**Model "Grupo Unidade"**

```
class GrupoUnidade(models.Model):   
    id_grupo = models.ForeignKey(
        Grupo,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    id_unidade = models.ForeignKey(
        Unidade,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'grupo_unidade'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

**Model "Unidade"**

```
class Unidade(models.Model):

    id_condominio = models.ForeignKey(
        Condominio,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True
    )
    tipo = models.ForeignKey(
        TipoUnidade,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    unidade = models.CharField(max_length=12)    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'unidade'
```

I've used the formset before but I don't know how to create this relationship and view.

I would like to know how to relate and create this listing.

Comment: I suppose you use [ChoicesJS](https://github.com/jshjohnson/Choices) it because it doesn't depend on jQuery.